# How to Consume from specific TopicPartitionOffset with Confluent.Kafka in .Net

Tags: .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I need my consumer to consume from an specific `TopicPartitionOffset(here from offset 278)`. Suppose that Messages have been produced by some Producer in Specific topic like `="Test_1"` before. 
Here is my Code

```
using System;
using Confluent.Kafka;

public class ConsumingTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig
                                 {
                                     BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092", EnableAutoCommit = false, GroupId = "this-group-id"
                                 };

        using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, string>(consumerConfig))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Consume Started...");
            consumer.Subscribe("Test_1");

            var topicPartitionOffset = new TopicPartitionOffset("Test_1", new Partition(0), new Offset(278));

            consumer.Assign(topicPartitionOffset);
            consumer.Seek(topicPartitionOffset);

            while (true)
                try
                {
                    var cr = consumer.Consume();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{cr.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
                }
                catch (ConsumeException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

at line ----> `var cr = consumer.Consume();` Consumer Consumes but nothing Happens. What is the problem.

I have already done `AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetResetType.Earliest` in ConsumerConfig , and Consumer Consumes All messages from all offsets but, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved: I found the solution which described as below:

- added this

`consumer.Assign(new TopicPartitionOffset(topicName, 0, new Offset(lastConsumedOffset)))` Before trying to Consume, and

- Removed these

`consumer.Subscribe("Test_1")` and `consumer.Seek(...)`

So Updated code is something like this which perfectly works:

```
using (var consumer = new Consumer<Ignore, string>(config))
            {
                consumer.Assign(topicName, 0, new Offset(lastConsumedOffset));
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var consumeResult = consumer.Consume();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Received message at {consumeResult.TopicPartitionOffset}: ${consumeResult.Value}");
                    }
                    catch (ConsumeException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Consume error: {e.Error}");
                    }
                }

                consumer.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Where did you find this solution? I can't find any documentation on .net beyond the very basic produce and consume

Comment: what is lastConsumedOffset?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira if you want always to read from start, then it's 0. https://i.imgur.com/2PIglmB.jpg

Comment: @BrunoFerreira 

lastConsumedOffset = consumer.Position(), I think